# How to show the data from a database into a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have problem in retrieving data in my spinner.

If String we can call it by

```
 text.setText(tex1);
 text2.setText(text2);
```

and how do i call text3 which is spinner into the setText? I know that setText is only for String but I don't know on how to call in in spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an ArrayAdapter and the following Documentary should help you out:
[Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)

Comment: A `CursorAdapter` might be appropriate here, too.